# Django CBV form using list of objects

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a form that is a list of cars with one field being a BooleanField.  I want this to appear as a form with the BooleanField being a checkbox.  If the user checks this, then the BooleanField will be set = True and something will happen when a POST occurs and the user is redirected to the next page.

**model.py:**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    make = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    send = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

currenly the **email.html** looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% for car in object_list %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="car" id="car{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ car.id }}"> 
            <label for="car{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ car.year }} {{ car.make }} {{ car.model }}</label><br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Preview">
    </form>
```

**views.py**

```
class Email(ListView):
    model = Car 
    template_name = 'cars/email.html'
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a `post()` function to the `ListView` which processes the form data, but I am having trouble redirecting without a valid HttpResponse object and am getting an error when one of the boxes isn't checked in the form.  Here is the additional post() code that I added for the time being:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    cars = Car.objects.all()  # initially reset "self.send" field == False
    for i in range(len(cars)):
        cars[i].send = False
        cars[i].save()
    cars = Car.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('car'))
    for i in cars:
        i.send = True
        i.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cars:email_preview'))
```

Any suggestions on how to make the form re-render with an error msg if no boxes are checked?

Thanks